# return id of an object with a specific class

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

if I have a page of iFrame objects with generated (unique) ids is it possible for me to return those ids if they .haveClass('specific_class')...
For instance: I want to scrape the entire page pick out elements with a specific class and return their unique ID how would I go about doing this?

I think I am misusing jquery's selector as it is not hitting true on my if statement.
//i've tried a few iterations of this to figure out the selector and I am still a bit confused.

```
if($(document).hasClass('specific_class'))
{
    alert("You found a iframe with this class");
    //return the iframe with this class's id
}
```

Any help is appreciated as I am pretty new to Jscript - as a side note I am doing this with ASP.net so I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Thanks,
Mitch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just do it with an each statement - don't even need the if statement

```
$('.specific_class').each(function(i,v){
    alert(v.id);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a little bit of functional fixedness on this one but your answer cleared everything up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to instead select all elements with that class and test it's length.

```
if ($(".specific_class").length) {
     //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $.map($('.specific_class'),function(item){
    return item.id;
});
```